# Django urls.py issue, not sure what to put in 'urlpatterns'

Tags: python, django

I've been following this tutorial ([Django Tutorial Part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/)) and I've stumbled across what I'm assuming is a syntax issue between the time this tutorial was written and the new Django releases. My admin page loads just fine.

[Code Block in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjbA0.png) So in the picture linked, that is the area that I am having trouble with from the tutorial. I think my "mysite/urls.py" file is fine, but the "polls/urls.py" file is where I'm not sure what to put.

Below is what mysite/urls.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

And here is what my polls/urls.py looks like:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(**??? not sure what to put here**, views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: You link to the documentation for Django version 1.8, I don't know if you notice but at the bottom right corner there is a _version selector_ and you can change the version for which you are looking at the docs. Hence here is the same link you gave only instead for Django 3.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/ In fact the snippet you ask about is in the first part of the tutorial in Django 3.2 docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Dude, life saver. I've been manually battling through the syntax differences. I mean, learning a lot in the process, but this is much easier haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the `polls/urls.py` file is where I'm not sure what to put.

The **empty string** (`''`), so:

```
urlpatterns [
    #    ↓↓ empty string
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

We can inspect how the path is compiled to a regex with:

```
>>> from django.urls import path
>>> pt = path('', lambda x: x)
>>> pt.pattern.regex
re.compile('^$')
```

The pattern is thus compiled to a regex `^$`, which is the same as the regex for the `url` pattern in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I was on the right track...I tried putting None in there lol.